# jQuery this.hash behavior for in page anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about how this.hash works for in page anchor links in jQuery.

I need to process the hash attribute every time the user clicks on that link.

```
<a href="#foo" class="inpageLink">Click Me!<"/a>
...
...
<a id="foo"></a>
<h3>Target Location</h3>
```

For the above HTML snippet, when I fetch the hash attribute, everything works fine.

```
$('.inpageLink').click(function(){
    var target = $(this.hash); 
    if (target.length != 0) {
        alert("found target" + this.hash);
    }
})
```

However, when I use name attribute instead of id attribute for the target, this.hash returns a null object.

```
<a href="#bar" class="inpageLink">Click Me!</a>
<a name="bar"></a>
<h3>Target Location</h3>
```

In this case, the click event does not fire the alert.

[The full example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/BQU3u/1/)

Can someone explain what I am missing over here or if this is how it is supposed to work?

Comment: The name attribute is not the same as the id attribute.  Name is typically used to indicate the name that should be used for a form parameter.  Other than that, it's pretty much useless.

Comment: @jjm: It's also used for anchors. Given URL `http://example.com/#foo`, the browser will jump to the element with ID `foo` or to the `a` element with name `foo`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`this.hash` will return `"#foo"` which is also a valid [*ID selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Hence `$(this.hash)` is the same as `$("#foo")` and will select the element with **ID** `foo`.
In your second example, you don't have an element with ID `bar`. Thus `$(this.hash)` won't select any element and `target.length` will be `0`.

---

Maybe you are confused by the fact that the browser still jumps to `<a name="bar"></a>`, although the `alert` is not shown. The browser does not behave the same as jQuery.

From the [HTML specification about the `name` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2):

> This attribute names the current anchor so that it may be the destination of another link. The value of this attribute must be a unique anchor name. The scope of this name is the current document. Note that this attribute shares the same name space as the id attribute.

So if the browser recognises a hash (fragment identifier) in the URL, it tries to find the first element with this ID or the first `a` element with that name.

In contrast, CSS ID selectors (that's what jQuery is using) only search for elements with that  ID, not for (`a`) elements with that name. Internally, jQuery is using `document.getElemenById`.

---

If the hash value is always referring to either an ID or a name, you can use the *multiple selector* to just make one selection:

```
$(this.hash + ', a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]')
```

In case there would be an element with this ID *and* an anchor with this name, you'd select all of them though.

Comment: Felix, thanks for the explanation. I think I understand what is going on now. I do not have control over determining if I will get an id or name on the target. I ended up solving this by first seeing if $(this.hash) exists. If it does not, doing a query for $('[name='+this.hash.substring(1)+']'). If that does not exist, I simply back out and let the browser do the default click event! I expected jQuery to do this for me, but oh well!

Comment: @Gunner4Life: If it is always either an ID or a name, you can use one selector: `$(this.href + ', a[name="' + this.href.substr(1) + '"]')`. I used `href` because I think it's more standard conform (could be wrong though ;)).

Comment: Ooh, one selector, I like that! I think I will stick onto this.hash, simply because I want to avoid the case where the HTML source has something like <a href="index.html#foo">Click Me</a>, when the user is actually on index.html page.

Comment: then what is $(this).hash() ?

Comment: @STEEL: A runtime error. jQuery objects don't have a `.hash` method (unless you included a plugin which provides that method).

Answer (score 1):

because the selector `$(this.hash)` finds nothing in the second case, `this.hash` return `#foo`  and then `$("#foo")` looks for the element with id `foo` which in the second case return nothing

http://jsfiddle.net/BQU3u/5/

Answer (score 0):

Why can't we use attr('href') - check this link

http://jsfiddle.net/BQU3u/11/

**Update**

Simply remove $ from $(this.hash)

http://jsfiddle.net/BQU3u/12/

Comment: We can but how does this answer the question? Your fiddle is flawed btw. `target` contains a string now which is not empty so it's length is always different than `0`. In the original code, `target` was referring to a jQuery object.

Comment: No. It only **appears** to work, because you changed what `target` is referring to. The equivalent code would be `target = $($(this).attr('href'));` (note the additional `$(...)`). Your fiddle does not what the OP wants to do and your argumentation is based on a false premise. If you want to show something, you have to replicate the behaviour of the OP's code, not change it.

Comment: Praveen, as Felix mentioned, now I get a string as my target and not the actual DOM element. I should have been more clearer about this in my problem statement.